# How to pass result of MapReduce into another MapReduce (java and hadoop)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have 6 `CSV` files that I need to run `MapReduce` on. Would it be best to join the data before hand (in `Python` or other tool), and then run it through `MapReduce`? or to complete the first `MapReduce`, and then feed the `.txt` result into the next `MapReduce` to summarise and join to the other datasets ? I am using `Java` and `Hadoop` and have pieced something together from examples I have found online. I am running this on a VM on my personal PC and am new to `Java` and `Hadoop`.

I am working with social media data and the first `MapReduce` I have gives the post IDs that have been flagged as offensive, and the number of times that they were flagged as offensive. Now I need to join this to the `CSV` that gives the user ID who put up that post, to finish with the top 10 users that had their posts flagged as offensive and a count of how many posts that was.

Any help to get me on the right track is appreciated!

Comment: Are all the CSVs the same "format"? MapReduce can read a whole directory of files. No need to merge them. Secondly, don't use Mapreduce unless you **have** to. At least use Spark (PySpark) or Hive (if you know SQL)

Comment: By the way, [Hadoop and MapReduce is not a place to learn Java programming](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopIsNot)

Comment: @cricket_007, yes all the CSVs are the same format. I'll try bringing the ones I need together into the same Mapper. Thanks for the link, I'll practice some simpler Java as well.

Comment: I still would strongly recommend you stick to Python if you know it and use PySpark. You don't need Hadoop to use Spark

Answer (score 0):

If all files are of same format , you can use multiple inputs or you can give entire directory as input.

For solving this, we can use FileInputFormat.addInputPaths() method, that can take a comma separated list of multiple inputs and we can write it as

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPaths("file0,file1,...")
```